# rx.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException when reading field LatLng.longitude on a null object

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, rx-java, rx-android

I'm new to FRP, in this case RxJava. As a part of learning by practicing, I decided to make a small project based on Google Maps. For this project, I'm using [RxGoogleMaps](https://github.com/sdoward/RxGoogleMaps) as one of the Rx replacement of the standard way.

A bit of a background for this project, I'm trying to create a bunch of marker clusters on the map using **ClusterManager** utility. Also, locating my location using the standard **LocationServices API**.

For the ClusterManager to work, it requires a GoogleMap object to be passed in the initialization parameter. I'm grabbing this object from `onMapReady` callback, which in I did using RxGoogleMaps like so,

```
/** Map Ready */
subscriptions.add(mapObservableProvider.getMapReadyObservable()
        .subscribe(googleMap -> {
            this.googleMap = googleMap;
        }));
```

My first question, is this consider a good practice on storing GoogleMap object to a variable, which it can be used later on? Correct me if I'm wrong, because it seems to me that it defeats the whole purpose of having a "stream on FRP".

Moving on, here is how I create the clustering markers using the standard way (RxGoogleMaps doesn't have this functionality)

```
private void initMarkers() {
    ClusterManager<ClusterMarkerLocation> clusterManager = new ClusterManager<>(this, googleMap);
    googleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(clusterManager);

    double lat, lng;
    Random generator = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        lat = generator.nextDouble() / 3;
        lng = generator.nextDouble() / 3;
        if (generator.nextBoolean()) {
            lat = -lat;
        }
        if (generator.nextBoolean()) {
            lng = -lng;
        }
        clusterManager.addItem(new ClusterMarkerLocation(new LatLng(mCenterLocation.latitude + lat, mCenterLocation.longitude + lng)));
    }
}
```

`mCenterLocation` is a variable that holds a LatLng object.

However, when I run this app, this error shows up, pointing out that there is an error in `initMarker()` method. Most probably caused by an unhandled exception when getting a null LatLng object.

> rx.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: Attempt to read from field 'double com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng.longitude' on a null object reference

I'm not entirely sure what is the problem because I'm so new at this. Some say that I have to make ClusterManager an Observable so that I can use it as streams. But how do I do that?

You can see the full code in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/aimanbaharum/720ce207dbff2c751aee52e923249403).

Any help and advice is much appreciated.

Comment: You receive NPE because `mCenterLocation` is not initialized. I would not use `rx` just for sake of `rx`. But rather use `rx` where it will add benefits.

Comment: Thanks for the advice :-)